# Override Rails Devise Controllers and get routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-jwt

I'm overriding Devise controllers in Rails like that:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Devise
      class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      ....
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And thats my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#index'

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :taxi_drivers, only: :passwords

  resources :taxi_drivers_groups, only: %i[index new create edit update]

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :users,
        defaults: { format: :json },
        class_name: 'User',
        skip: %i[registrations sessions passwords],
        path: '',
        path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }

      devise_scope :user do
        post 'signup', to: 'devise/registrations#create'
        post 'login',  to:'devise/sessions#create'
        delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
        post 'password_recover', to: 'devise/passwords#create'
        put 'password_recover', to: 'devise/passwords#update'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm getting an error when I try to pass my tests:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::Devise::RegistrationsController
```

And in my test file:

```
test 'user invalid sigup with empty fields' do
  @valid_signup_params[:name] = nil

  post('/api/v1/signup.json', { user: @valid_signup_params }, headers: { format: :json })

  assert_equal last_response.status, 422
  assert_equal json_response['errors']['name'].count, 1
end
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: What's happening if if you replace `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` with: `class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController`. Do you have the same error ?

Comment: Glad it fixed your issue. I've added my comment as an answer if you want to add it as the best answer, it would be nice, thx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues comes from a constant clash between the newly defined controller and the existing one.

Replacing `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` with `class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController` is fixing the issue as ruby knows that he has to find the `RegistrationsController` class in the previously defined `Devise` module and not in the current definition.

Comment: Technically what `::Devise` does is explicitly resolve the constant from the root namespace instead of the current module nesting.

Comment: Yep, that's true :+1: